# Unable to use Jinja variable inside adapter.get_relation in DBT

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am trying to use a Jinja variable inside my adapter.get_relation but I am unable to do so :confused: The code

```
{% set the_var = 'amazon_full_orders_denormalized_' ~ company_uuid %}

{{ log(the_var, info=True) }}

{%- set source_relation = adapter.get_relation(
      database='282615',
      schema='airbyte_mumbai',
      identifier= the_var ) -%}
```

The command I am using

```
dbt compile --vars '{"company_uuid":"0703afd3_496b_4ed5_8e0c_594b71f4718b","dataset":"airbyte_mumbai"}' --models tag:copy_reports
```

The variable the_var is getting set to `amazon_full_orders_denormalized_`

```
Found 6 models, 0 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 165 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 0 sources, 0 exposures

17:11:08 | Concurrency: 3 threads (target='dev')
17:11:08 | 
amazon_full_orders_denormalized_
Table does not exist
17:11:08 | Done.
```

Whereas I am expecting it to be set to `amazon_full_orders_denormalized_0703afd3_496b_4ed5_8e0c_594b71f4718b`

Comment: Instead of `identifier = the_var`, try this `identifier=the_var+var('company_uuid')`. I think the `company_uuid` variable is not getting appended to the variable `the_var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables in dbt can be hard sometimes! I think the commenter @Kay is on the right track here in that you have three variables happening here: `the_var`, `company_uuid`, and `dataset`. It looks as if you'd like the a table name that is the concatenation of `the_var` and `company_uuid`, which you can do using jinja's concat operators, `~`, like this:

```sql
-- just for testing
{{ log(the_var, info=True) }}
{{ log(var('company_uuid'), info=True) }}
{{ log(the_var ~ var('company_uuid'), info=True) }}

-- see change to `identifier`
{%- set source_relation = adapter.get_relation(
      database='282615',
      schema='airbyte_mumbai',
      identifier= the_var ~ var('company_uuid') ) -%}
```

Comment: Thanks Anders. This is what I was looking for. I tried multiple ways using `~ company_uuid` / `~ {{ company_uuid }}` / `~ {{ var("company_uuid") }}` but none of them was working

Comment: I get it -- jinja is weird sometimes! just remember that you don't need curly brackets to reference variables if you're already inside curly brackets